# How will I know how many photos are generated using ImageDataGeneration and fit_generator()?

Tags: python, keras

I am using ImageDataGenerator from Keras to implement data augmentation in Python. I use it in this way:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                   rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

#dodanie augmentacji danych dla danych walidacyjnych
valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#pobranie danych treningowych
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dir,
                                                   target_size=(224,224),
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='binary')

#pobranie danych walidacyjnych
valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=valid_dir,
                                                   target_size=(224,224),
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='binary')
```

And then I train a model:

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch=400,
                             epochs=5,    # 100
                             validation_data=valid_generator,
                             validation_steps=160, callbacks=[checkpt])
```

How will I know how many images are generated during training? I mean is there a way to fiind out on how many pictures the model was trained?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally wrong your `valid_datagen` and `train_datagen` produce 32 images in one go (defined through the `batch_size`) and you activate it 400 times on each Epoch (`steps_per_epoch`) and that 5 Times (5 `epochs`). That leads to 32*400*5 = **64.000 Training-Images**. For Validation, you use 32*160 = **5.120 Validation-Images**.
But it is not impossible that some of the generated Images are equal to each other. Each Batch has randomly Generated Images, so there is a chance of replication.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but that should be the way it works